# Can the mq server/client TLS keystore stash file reside elsewhere

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-mq

I have a scenario where the Security administrator is concerned with having the stash file residing on ec2/AWS disk with the keystore files and asks if there are any configuration options in v9.2 to retrieve KDB password dynamically from a password store and pass it to the Queue Manager for authenticating TLS connections. He understands the stash file is encrypted but concerned with having the stash fileon ec2/AWS.

Comment: are you looking for an AWS Secret Manager service for this?

Answer (score 0):

The queue managers on z/OS and mid range use system ssl, which uses the CMS API to do the TLS work.
I'm familiar with the toolkit on z/OS.
There are API requests to open database and open database using stash file.  I havent seen anything in MQ that says you can pass key store password to it.

If there were a way of passing in the password, have you just moved the problem?   If someone has access to the stash file, then someone may have access to your password store.  If you want to automate starting MQ, then somewhere will be the password to the password store.

I got round this by using an Hardware Security Module (USB).  Although the password to access it is stored somewhere, the actual file is on the HSM USB device.  To get the data you need access to the physical device.

See my post https://colinpaice.blog/2021/03/08/initial-setup-for-using-a-keystore-on-a-hsm-usb-stick/.   The nitrokey device was not that expensive - and pretty easy to use.